# How to Make Bootcamp Windows 7 Folders Accessible in Mac OS

Tags: bootcamp, macos, windows

Installed windows 7 on Bootcamp partition. I want to copy files to my Windows 7 folder from Mac OS but do not have appropriate permissions, when I drag something to any windows folder it doesn't allow it.

Comment: You need a third party app as the NTFS driver Apple supplies is read only

Comment: @Mark, Unless things have changed, your comment it technically wrong. While a 3rd party driver is a better way to go, nonetheless Apple's supplied NTFS driver **is** read/write capable. You just have to manually mount the volume as read/write or set it so, per its UUID or Label  in `/etc/fstab`.